# Missing PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase when using codecept.phar and yii

Tags: yii, phpunit, codeception

There are a lot of questions about `"phpunit/phpunit_story"` module, and here is another one:

We're using Yii with `Codeception`, which contains PHPUnit, but missing the `PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase.php` module. We're also not using `pear` or `composer`. Everytime I'm running /utests I'm getting following warning:

```
PHP Warning:  include(PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /*/framework/YiiBase.php on line 421
```

There are a lot of answers about how to fix this problem with pear or composer, but is there any other way to deal with this warning?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when your autoloader is too eager, ie. when it tries to load sourcecode files for classes it is not responsible for.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, I have already realized that it's an autoloader problem. Do you have any suggestion what can I do about that problem?

Comment: To clarify: I'm using standard Yii autoloader and standard codeception.phar file